# How to install Tamil language package in Magento2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, language-package, multi-language

Magento doesn't have a Tamil language package in the locale option of the admin panel. How to install a custom 'Tamil' language package and use it.

Following these steps(image) able to add in the adminpanel, But it's **not translating**, How to configure with Tamil lang package?
[image]

Tried this below link also,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067460/how-to-install-a-language-pack-in-magento-2

Not worked. Please share your solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for your information. `Magento2 doesn't have any official or custom Tamil (தமிழ்) language packages available` AFAIK. Sadly there exists no language package with ta_IN. (Yes it's a shame really)

[All the available Magento2 language packs can be found here](https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2)

https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2

Your question has been answered.

---

***Solution***: `Let's create a Tamil Language Package for Magento2`. It's high time to make Magento world understand the world's oldest and richest classical language.

Let me take the initiative for this project and create a new language pack for Tamil this week and any Tamil enthusiasts in Magento community can join and contribute to this language pack.

PS: I'll keep this thread updated once the package is ready.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, Magento world should include the Tamil language also, but it's not... Anyway, I tried creating a new custom language package. But it's not worked. Please share the Tamil language package once you are done with that or any reference link to follow.